# Sublime Text 3 - Use Cygwin instead of cmd for build systems

Tags: cygwin, sublime-text-3

I just installed Cygwin and would like to use that for ST3's build system instead of CMD. 
I can't seem to find good documentation about it. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same question and solved it with reading some related Question-Thread on Stackoverflow, which I listed at the End of my answer.

**Overview of what I answer:**

[image: Working Solution to get Sublime Text to Build through Cygwin.]

---

## 1. Create shell-script file `SublimeTextBuildScript.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/bash -l

cd "/cygdrive/x/cheatsheet-template"
ls -lha 
make
```

### 1.1 Optional: Switch the line-ending

[image: Changing Lineending Setting in Sublime Text - Trouble with written shell-scripts from/via Sublime Text]

**Solves:** Troubles while executing the shell-script with Line-endings. I saw some error-messages with "\r" in the message while testing.

### 1.2 Helpfully: *Mintty Command Line Options*

[image: Helpfully to get it done: Mintty Command Line Options]

## 2. (Test-)Command for SublimeText Custom Build System:

`D:\Applications\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -h always /cygdrive/d/Applications/Hochguertel/bin/SublimeTextBuildScript.sh`

### 2.1 Testing result

[image: Testing your Solution (Build-Script) from/via Windows Command Shell]

## 3. Put it all together

### 3.1 Create an Build System

`Sublime Text -> Tools -> Build-System -> New Build System...`

[image: Sublime Text -> Tools -> Build-System -> New Build System...]

### 3.2 Configure the Build System

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "D:\\Applications\\cygwin64\\bin\\mintty.exe -h always
 /cygdrive/d/Applications/Hochguertel/bin/SublimeTextBuildScript.sh"
}
```

[image: Configuration of the new Build System in Sublime 3 with Cygwin (Mintty.exe)]

### 3.3 Save the configurated Build System

**File-Extension:** `.sublime-build`

Filename: `Cheatsheet Build.sublime-build`

[image: Save the Cygwin (Mintty.exe) Sublime Text Build System - Cheatsheet Build.sublime-build]

### 3.4 Activating the created Build System

`Sublime Text -> Tools -> Build System -> "Cheatsheet Build"`

[image: Selecting the created Build System]

## 4.0 Testing the Cygwin Environment Build System via Sublime Text

`Sublime Text -> Tools -> Build`

[image: Run Build]

> **Working Cygwin Build System Solution with Sublime Text:**
>
> [image: Working Cygwin Build System Solution with Sublime Text]

## Sources of information (Stackoverflow Links)

- [Fixing Sublime Text 2 line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11899843/fixing-sublime-text-2-line-endings)
- [how to automate cygwin and mintty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15934068/how-to-automate-cygwin-and-mintty)
- [How do i start Mintty and run a script file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977038/how-do-i-start-mintty-and-run-a-script-file)

HTH